# Using Oracle Instant Client with macOS Monterey

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

I’m having this issue installing the Oracle instant client on my MacBook Air M1:

> DPI-1047 cannot locate 64-bit oracle client library dlopen(libclntsh.dlyb)

Someone already did it before?

Comment: You will need to use x64 tools with the Instant Client for macOS Intel x86 packages, and also use Rosetta.  There are various posts about this.  But, if you happen to be a Python user, you can natively use the latest release of Oracle's python driver, now known as [python-oracledb](https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/) since it doesn't need Instant Client by default.  See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones I solved after your comment thanks really helpful

Comment: @ ulises-capistrán which solution did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the "Basic Package" zip for version 19.8.0.0.0:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

Once you have downloaded, unzip the files and move them to `/usr/local/lib` folder. This should solve your issue.

You may run into a security issue opening the files, in that case you will need to open them individually on the finder in order to manually allow mac to trust them.

Comment: On my mac there is no folder lib under /usr/local